# Sandboxing Javascript

Tags: javascript, sandbox

Except for Caja(which is Java based) is there a simple javascript implementation for sandboxing iframes?

Comment: I don't think there is, you might need to use Sandboxie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the iframe from a different domain, and the same origin policy will sandbox any scripts.

Comment: Iframes are an isolation mechanism, not a security mechanism.

From http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/ :
Today, some websites embed third-party code using iframes. This approach does not prevent a wide variety of attacks: redirection to phishing pages which could pretend to be a login page for the embedding application; stopping the browser from working until the user downloads malware; stealing history information ... so that more target phishing attacks can be done... once [a website] has [given user data] ... it cannot stop the iframe app from sending that data elsewhere.